# Change Build Settings in Xamarin.IOS to comply with IOS 12 Changes

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.ios, ios12

With the addition of IOS 12 and the IOS 12 simulators no longer supporting libstdc++, how do we change the build setting to libc++ for an existing project? I looked all over and even opened the project in atom to globally search for the setting and could not find it.

Comment: library such as libc++ and libstdc++ are been included in the Xcode ,not VS. So they  will be  set automatically when you build the project.And you do not need to set them.Did you get some errors when you build an existing project?

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Yes. When i was moving my project from a windows machine to mac it started throwing errors which summarize to mean libstdc++ not found. Which is reasonable when developing on a ios 12 simulator and old project. However, if i create a brand new project, it launches to an ios 12 simulator just fine.

Comment: Try to delete the folder bin and obj,then rebuild the project.